# why ModelMapper takes mapping via method reference?

Tags: java, method-reference, modelmapper

```
@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    ModelMapper m = new ModelMapper();
    TypeMap<BatchDTO, Batch> typeMap = m.typeMap(BatchDTO.class, Batch.class);
    typeMap.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.skip(Batch::setProgram));
    return m;
}
```

Why does it take a configuration via method reference, e.g. `mapper.skip(Batch::setProgram)`?

Answer (score 0):

Because [skip](http://modelmapper.org/javadoc/org/modelmapper/builder/ReferenceMapExpression.html#skip-org.modelmapper.spi.DestinationSetter-) accepts parameter of type [DestinationSetter](http://modelmapper.org/javadoc/org/modelmapper/spi/DestinationSetter.html). DestinationSetter has a single abstract method, which makes it equivalent to a functional interface, even though it is not annotated with [FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html).

Functional interfaces can be implementated via lambda expressions and method references. You could check [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) or [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces) for more info.